# retrieving JSON value based on another value from the same object

Tags: jquery, json

I'm just delving into JSON and need to basically pull a value based on another objects value.
so, for each objects "id" , I need to return the "name".

Here's the JSON:

```
  { 
   "competitors":

  [
   {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "tooltiptitle": "John Doe",
    "tooltip": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. ",
    "id": 0,
    "round": 1
},
{
    "name": "jane Doe",
    "tooltiptitle": "jane Doe",
    "tooltip": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. ",
    "id": 1
}
]
}


        $(document).ready(function() {
         $(function() {
          $.getJSON('https://github.com/gregdsign/json-test/blob/master/feed.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data.competitors, function(i, cmp) {
            $('body').append('<div class="bracketContainer tooltip" id="bracket' + i + '"' + '>' + '<div class="bracket-content">' + '<span class="bracketIds">' + cmp.id + '</span>' + '<span class="bracketNames">' + cmp.name + '</span>' + '</div>' + '<div class="tipContent">' + '<span class="tooltipTitle">' + cmp.tooltiptitle + '</span>' + '<span class="tooltipP">' + cmp.tooltip + '</span>' + '</div>' + '</div>');
        });
    });
  });
 });
```

Instead of using    cmp.name   How could I pull the name based on the id of each object?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? What's wrong with what you currently have?

Comment: sure. So...basically...instead of calling each value of "name" through the cmp.name in my js...I want to call that value by the id.

Comment: so imageine the line '<span class="bracketIds">' + cmp.id + '</span>'  ..that would be hidden and in another div, it would display the 'name' value of each id...hopefully that makes sense

Comment: So you want a function like `getNameByID(id)` that returns the name?

Comment: right so.. for each id that is created by cmp.id ... a function grabs that name value associated with each id and pulls it into a div.