# Aquiring JSON objects value for another value within same object

Tags: javascript, json

```
lol.lewl = {
    value: 'something',
    anotherValue: lol.lewl.value+' and something else'
}
```

Saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096499/retrieving-json-value-based-on-another-value-from-the-same-object), didn't answer it. I reckon you know what I'm trying to do here, I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined
```

Comment: Why not just assign `anotherValue` after creating `lol.lewl`? Such as: `lol.lewl = {value: "something"}; lol.lewl.anotherValue = lol.lewl.value+' and something else'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that.  You are in the process of declaring `lol.lewl`, so it doesn't know what that is yet.

You'll have to do this:

```
lol.lewl = {
    value: 'something'
};

lol.lewl.anotherValue = lol.lewl.value+' and something else';
```

Comment: Good explination, perfect!